# How to use the loop in the file input change event

Tags: javascript, file, loops, for-loop, dom

Hello I have the following code

```js
function fileValidation() {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('filech');
  var filePath = fileInput.value;
  var allowedExtensions = /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$/i;
  if (!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) {
    alert('error .jpeg/.jpg/.png/.gif ');
    fileInput.value = '';
    return false;
  } else {
    //Image preview
    if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        document.getElementById('imagePreview').innerHTML = '<img src="' + e.target.result + '"/>';
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="filech" type="file" name="file_img[]" multiple onchange="return fileValidation()" />

<div id="imagePreview"></div>
```

To upload photos by

```
   <input  id="filech"  type="file" name="file_img[]" multiple onchange="return fileValidation()" />
```

then show

```
<div id="imagePreview"></div>
```

I want to show all the pictures and not one

How to use the loop here and thank all

Comment: Have you tried looping through the `fileInput.files` array? You can just add an image instead of setting the `innerHTML` of the `imagePreview` element.

Comment: How this happens array !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you said you will need a loop, the easiest way would be to use a `for` loop, like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
      if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[i]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          document.getElementById('imagePreview').innerHTML += '<img src="' + e.target.result + '"/>';
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[i]);
      }
    }
```

**Note:**

Note that I changed it to `document.getElementById('imagePreview').innerHTML +=`, so it keep printing all the iterated images, otherwise it will just override the preview with the last image content.

But the best practice is to create an `img` element on each iteration and append it to the preview div:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
  if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[i]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = e.target.result;
      document.getElementById('imagePreview').appendChild(img);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[i]);
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function fileValidation() {
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('filech');
  var filePath = fileInput.value;
  var allowedExtensions = /(\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif)$/i;
  if (!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)) {
    alert('error .jpeg/.jpg/.png/.gif ');
    fileInput.value = '';
    return false;
  } else {
    //Image preview
    for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
      if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files[i]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          img.src = e.target.result;
          document.getElementById('imagePreview').appendChild(img);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(fileInput.files[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="filech" type="file" name="file_img[]" multiple onchange="return fileValidation()" />


<div id="imagePreview"></div>
```

Comment: You really are wonderful you've helped me like lightning and thank chŝdk

Comment: @SAUDIARBIA You are more than welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: A final question is how to clear imagePreview Before uploading photos and thank you ):

Comment: Just before the loop write `document.getElementById("imagePreview").innerHTML = "";`.